How to show typed letter values in autocomplete textbox from a datatable column in C# windows application
I have a datatable named Tb_ItemCreation, it is having a column named finalname. that finalname column having so many words values. I want to load finalname column values to a autocomplete  textbox and when I type a single letter in textbox. I want to show values having the typed letter included only and not show other values have this typed letter.
For example: my table column having values like eat,beat,mat,jar. if i typed "e" letter then it must show only beat, eat.
I have tried a lot of methods like text changed method , list string, key press, key up, timer tick. etc.. but it does not give me result
